# Javascript concatenar variables y string

Tags: javascript

Al concatenar un string con las variables, no se realizan bien las operaciones. Cuando se realiza la suma, al poner la cadena "Suma", se concatenan las variables, en cambio si las quito, se suman bien.

```
function mates(){
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Numero 1"));
  var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Numero 2"));
  result.innerHTML = "Suma"+num1 + num2+ "<br />";
  result.innerHTML += "Resta" +num1 - num2;
}

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input id="bot1" type="button" value="F1" onclick="mates()" />
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No hay necesidad de concatenar de esa forma, mejor emplea *template strings*.

Quedando de este modo

```
result.innerHTML = `Suma ${num1 + num2} <br />`
result.innerHTML += `Resta ${num1 - num2}`
```

- De esta forma solo necesitas interpolar entre llaves operación matemática a resolver
- Tu sintaxis será más corta
- El salto de línea con la etiqueta `br` puede quedar dentro de los mismos *bakcticks*

Aquí puedes revisar su [soporte](https://caniuse.com/#search=template-) el cual es amplio en los navegadores.

Y [aquí la fuente donde puedes leer más al respecto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score 9):

Has probado a poner paréntesis?

```
result.innerHTML = "Suma" + (num1 + num2) + "<br />";
result.innerHTML += "Resta" + (num1 - num2);
```

Con los paréntesis indicas la prioridad de las operaciones.